# req.body.username being undefined

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

in express js, i am using body parser to get the username. when i try to get the username, it returns undefined. Can anyone help me?

```
app.use(session({
 cookieName: 'session',
 secret: "Shh_It's_a_secret",
 duration: 100000 * 100000
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
if(req.body.username){
 res.send('Invalid Username, Press The Back Button To Try Again');
} else if (!req.body.username) {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/NerdFestProjectHomepage.html'));
  res.sendfile('NerdFestProjectHomepage.html');
  console.log(req.body.username);
}
})
```

When i try to get req.body.username, it returns undefined.

Comment: Please specify your view code too or are you just exposing APIs?

Comment: YOu do realize you're sending an "invalid username" message when you *do* have a username, right?

Comment: I know that, i was just using that for a test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a GET request.
In express it is not possible to send "body" using GET request.

Change GET to POST request :

```
app.post('/home', cb );
```

And in view use :

```
<form action="/home" method="POST"></form>
```

Comment: @Ankizle if it helped you please upvote and approve it. I have edited the formatting too.

Comment: It should be `app.post('/home',cb);`, not `app.post('/home',cb());`.